# Adding plain text to navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I am editing horizontal navigation bar and need to add description text before the links. My problem that all the text displays after links in the browser. How can I modify css or code to change the location of the text in nav bar? 'DIRECTORIES:' and 'SEARCH:' That I need to display in the browser just before the links, not after

```
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="navlist">
    <li id="active"><a href="index2.php" id="current">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="smartchartquick.php">SEARCH: Product Technologies</a></li>
    <li><a href="clinicaltrialsquick.php">Trials &amp; Registries</a></li>

    <li> <a href="">DIRECTORIES: PIs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PI Study Sites</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Products</a>
    <li><a href="companies.php">Companies/Sponsors</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.medintellibasealerts.com" target="_blank">MIB Custom Alerts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just type your description text before the `<a href="whatever">`, e.g. `<li>Description <a href="blah">Link</a></li>`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but isn't it as easy as going from this:

`<li><a href="smartchartquick.php">SEARCH: Product Technologies</a></li>`

to

`<li>label goes here<a href="smartchartquick.php">SEARCH: Product Technologies</a></li>`

Edit: In regards to your comment, why not: `<li>Search</li>`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I need 'SEARCH' without a link. In the navigation bar it should look like: SEARCH: 'Product Technologies(link)'   'Trials and Registries(link)'. But it pushes 'SEARCH' to the end of the nav bar

Comment: I already tried it. It displays SEARCH: and DIRECTORIES: after all the links on the right side of the menu instead of before corresponding links.